# Multiple rows in single field separated by commas SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Simulating group_concat MySQL function in MS SQL Server 2005?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/451415/simulating-group-concat-mysql-function-in-ms-sql-server-2005)

What will be the SQL Server code to achieve this result:

```
SO number  Line number            
123           6
123          189
456           34
```

Output required:

```
SO number  Line number 
 123            6,189
 456               34
```

Comment: This question is so incredibly duplicate. Googling for "SQL Server concat aggregate" must return an infinite amount of results.

Comment: group_concat is only used with MYSQL I suppose?Isn't it?

Comment: @user1561175: Yes, `GROUP_CONCAT` is a MySQL function. SQL Server doesn't have a direct equivalent. That's why the other question was about *simulating* that function in SQL Server.

Answer (score 4):

Try this :-

```
CREATE TABLE #Sample ([SO Number] INT, [Line Number] INT)

INSERT INTO #Sample ([SO Number],[Line Number]) VALUES (123,6)
INSERT INTO #Sample ([SO Number],[Line Number]) VALUES (123,189)
INSERT INTO #Sample ([SO Number],[Line Number]) VALUES (456,34)


SELECT ID,
STUFF((
SELECT ', ' + cast([Line Number] as varchar(max) )
FROM #Sample 
WHERE ([SO Number] = a.[SO Number]) 
FOR XML PATH (''))
,1,2,'') AS b
FROM #Sample a
GROUP BY [SO Number]
```

Edit :

```
XML PATH (''):Is used to retrieve the column values seperated by comma 
Ex:- ,6,189,34
```

[STUFF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188043.aspx): Is used to insert a string into another string .The expression is

```
STUFF ( character_expression , start , length ,character_expression )
```

Start length is 1 since we have to replace the first comma created by XML PATH .
    Length   is 1 for the space `''` which is being inserted

So even if you have 20K rows the expression will remain same as 1,2 is used to insert space

Comment: i think its a silly doubt.but i am not that great with sql.my actual data has more than 20,000 rows.how would i write 1,2,'' in that case.

Comment: that is how should 7th line of your given code be modified?

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @Sample Table([SO Number] INT, [Line Number] INT)

INSERT INTO @Sample ([SO Number],[Line Number]) VALUES (123,6)
INSERT INTO @Sample ([SO Number],[Line Number]) VALUES (123,189)
INSERT INTO @Sample ([SO Number],[Line Number]) VALUES (456,34)

select * from @Sample

select [SO Number],STUFF((select ','+cast([Line Number] as varchar(100)) from  @Sample s1 where s1.[SO Number] =s.[SO Number]  FOR XML path('')),1,1,'' )  as [Line Number]     from  @Sample s
group by [SO Number]
```